# java managed server bean crashes

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

Why would I not be able to call this multiple times?

```
 private Document getStationery(String txtStationery,Database mailDB){
      try {
        View mailView = mailDB.getView("(Stationery)");
        DocumentCollection dc = mailView.getAllDocumentsByKey("Memo Stationery");
        Document tmpdoc;
          Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
          while (doc != null) {
             if(doc.getItemValueString("MailStationeryName").equals(txtStationery))
            {
                return doc;
            }
            tmpdoc = dc.getNextDocument();
            doc.recycle();
            doc = tmpdoc;
          }
         
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
      
  }
```

Crashes on second use of it below .... something to do with not recycling?

```
public void send() throws NotesException, IOException, Exception{
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Database userDB = getUserDatabase();
    Database mailbox = session.getDatabase("", "mail1.box");
    Document stationeryDoc1 = getStationery("Test1",userDB);
    Document stationeryDoc2 = getStationery("Test2",userDB);
```

Comment: Do you mean crash at runtime or compile error? Second code should show compile error (stationeryDoc declared twice)

Comment: Sorry Knut - I've updated the code above - compiles OK - I can't seem to run the getStationery twice

Comment: What is the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: Caused by: NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
 at lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.CheckObject(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.local.Document.getItemValueString(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.xsp.utils.EmailBean.send(EmailBean.java:236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try without recycling at all (generally not a good idea, but here it may be helpful to rule out other problems), or recycle the objects in the getStationary() method properly, beginning with the Document, the DocumentCollection, and finally the View. At the moment, the only object you recycle is the previous Document object in the while loop.

Comment: removed recylce

Comment: I actually meant you could remove the recycle call for testing purposes. Now that you know that the problem was really due to a recycling problem, you need to implement it properly for all objects (view, collection, document) in the method. Otherwise you will leak memory.

Comment: Did you try recycling also the DocumentCollection object? I suspect not recycling it may cause dead backend objects to remain in memory, which may lead to the infamous "Object has been removed or recycled" exception.